# PHP - Variable Questions

Tags: php, variables

Not sure of a better title for this question but basically heres my code:

```
<?php

$v = file_get_contents('http://examplecom/index.php?=');

$popularnames = array('Gravity Falls','The Amazing World of Gumball','South Park','American Dad');

?>
```

Basically what im trying to do is reference the $popularnames array in different areas so like in my href for example this is what i need:

```
<a href="<?= $v.urlencode($popularnames[0]); ?>"><?= $popularnames[0]; ?></a>
```

Basically what it should be doing is adding popularnames[0] (Gravity Falls) url encoded to the file_get_contents url of $v but for some reason all it does is output Gravity Falls

But my result should have gotten me `http://example.com/index.php?=Gravity+Falls` and then have do file_put_contents to it and its result should then have been Hello World! or whatever the page was displaying.

I cant just add $popularname[0] to the $v as im using the $v in multiple href's so doing that it will make all the hrefs one url but I want them different like:

```
<a href="<?= $v.urlencode($popularnames[0]); ?>"><?= $popularnames[0]; ?></a>

<a href="<?= $v.urlencode($popularnames[0]); ?>"><?= $popularnames[1]; ?></a>

<a href="<?= $v.urlencode($popularnames[0]); ?>"><?= $popularnames[2]; ?></a>
```

Using this works fine doe so theres no issue with what the variable contain:

```
<?php $v = file_get_contents('http://example.com/index.php?q='.urlencode($popularnames[0])); echo $v; ?>
```

Any ideas?

From an answer below how can I make it more compact so it would preferably make me able to just do `<?= $v.$v2.$popularnames[0]; ?>`:

```
<?php
$v = 'http://example.com/index.php?q=';
$v2 = file_get_contents($v.urlencode($popularnames[0])); echo $v2;
?>
```

Do note that the echoed $v2 will be echoed inside a `src=" "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But my result should have gotten me http://example.com/index.php?=Gravity+Falls

Then just store the URL fragment in `$v`:

```
$v = 'http://examplecom/index.php?=';
```

Currently you're *getting the file contents* of that URL fragment and storing *that* in `$v`:

```
$v = file_get_contents('http://examplecom/index.php?=');
```

If the contents of that incomplete URL are empty, then naturally `$v` would be empty.  And concatenating an empty string with another string would result in just that other string.

(Side note: I'm not sure what you plan to do at `index.php` since the query string value you're sending doesn't have a *key* associated with it.  Maybe you forgot to include the key in the URL fragment?)

Comment: Perfect, But is there a way to make it neater and more compact:
Edited main post

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436: Define "neater and more compact".  Setting string values to variables is about as simple and "compact" as it gets.

Comment: As in how can I get it to be able to do <?= $v.$v2.$popularnames[0]; ?> and <?= $v.$v2.$popularnames[1]; ?> e.t.c wherever I want it to do file_get_contents.

Comment: @Kyubeh2435436: You can't alias a function call to a variable name.  You have to actually call the function.  You can store the *result* of the function call in a variable.  But `$v2.$something` can't directly replace `function($something)`.

Comment: This is the most compact I could get it <?= file_get_contents($v.urlencode($popularnames[0])); ?> it will do.